# Where clausole in LINQ on Razorpage don't work

Tags: c#, linq, razor-pages

i'm developing a Razor WebApp and when i use this LINQ code, it doesn't work as aspected.
This is my Razor code:

```
var menuItems = menus.GetMenuMaster(@UserRoles).Result.Where(n => n.Parent_MenuID == "*");    

@foreach (var menuNames in menuItems)
{
   var submenus = menuItems.Where(n => n.Parent_MenuID == menuNames.MenuID))
}
```

The DB contains this data:

```
   ID   | MenuID    | MENUNAME  | Parent_MenuID
---------------------------------------------------
    1   | HOME      | HOME      | *
    2   | MOVIES    | MOVIES    | *
    3   | ACTORS    | ACTORS    | MOVIES
```

The problem is that "submenus" are empty for HOME menu, but must have the ACTORS submenu; "menuItems" contain all the tree menu items.

Comment: The problem is not outputting submenus to the page; menu items show correctly on my page; the problem is that submenus is not showing because are empty. Thanks for the link; very helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite like:

```
var allmenus = menus.GetMenuMaster(@UserRoles).Result;
var menuItems = allmenus.Where(n => n.Parent_MenuID == "*");    

@foreach (var menuNames in menuItems)
{
   var submenus = allmenus.Where(n => n.Parent_MenuID == menuNames.MenuID))
}
```

Updated:

In your code you filtered menus by condition `n.Parent_MenuID == "*"` and then in loop you try find items in filtered collection by condition `n.Parent_MenuID == menuNames.MenuID`. But your collection (after first filtering) don't have already such items.

Comment: Thanks Roma; it works. I've change allmenu.Where with allmenu.Result.Where.